# Issue on Arm with the Kitware APT: does not have a Release file

Tags: cmake, arm, apt

There is an issue since few days using the Kitware PPA for APT on Arm64:

```bash
Ign:13 https://apt.kitware.com/ubuntu focal InRelease
Err:14 https://apt.kitware.com/ubuntu focal Release
  Certificate verification failed: The certificate is NOT trusted. The received OCSP status response is invalid.  Could not handshake: Error in the certificate verification. [IP: 66.194.253.25 443]
Hit:9 https://packagecloud.io/github/git-lfs/ubuntu focal InRelease
Reading package lists... Done
E: The repository 'https://apt.kitware.com/ubuntu focal Release' does not have a Release file.
```

It is easily reproducible using the official instructions on the Kitware website: https://apt.kitware.com/

1. `wget -O - https://apt.kitware.com/keys/kitware-archive-latest.asc 2>/dev/null | gpg --dearmor - | sudo tee /usr/share/keyrings/kitware-archive-keyring.gpg >/dev/null`
2. `echo 'deb [signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/kitware-archive-keyring.gpg] https://apt.kitware.com/ubuntu/ focal main' | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/kitware.list >/dev/null`
3. `sudo apt-get update`

I contacted the support and search for solutions to avoid this error (skip the sefety check, etc.).

Comment: note to whoever voted to close this an not about programming, this is a question about the installation of a programmer tool. see also https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/423563/11107541. But as answered, this question is not reproducible, so it should be closed for that reason.

Comment: @user: The error is clearly on the side of `apt` and software repositories. One could face with that error irrespectively what kind of software they are installing. That is, the error is not **specific** to a programming. The error is described e.g. on AskUbuntu: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1095266/apt-get-update-failed-because-certificate-verification-failed-because-handshake

Comment: I am still getting this error. How were you able to solve this ?

Comment: @AhsanJamal as mentioned, it is not specific to Kitware APT. As Said Tsyvarev "One could face with that error irrespectively what kind of software they are installing."

They probably have a low performance APT mirror for ARM.

To avoid, such issue, I created my own APT mirror with copies of the dependencies I need such as the one from Kitware.
One guide for that is: https://www.linuxtechi.com/setup-local-apt-repository-server-ubuntu/

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be working now. For anyone who is experiencing this problem, try to diagnose your problem as much as possible until you are sure that the problem is with the provider's APT mirror.

Then either change the APT to a more stable one, or contact them to make sure they are aware of the problem so they can fix it.